# Detect hardware changes

Tags: wpf, real-time, hardware

So I am attempting to create a WPF application for a tablet. This tablet is being used interchangeably with/without a keyboard dock, with an attached USB keyboard if the dock is not present, and if neither the dock or Keyboard is not present I want the OSK (On-Screen Keyboard) to popup if a textbox is focused.

My main objective at this moment is to detect (real-time) hardware changes to see if there is a keyboard present, whether it be the docking station keyboard or USB keyboard.

I've seen posts on ASHWID, but I do not know what to look for in the hardware ID that is returned. Is there some type of event handler I can put into place to detect these changes any time they are made?

Comment: Any particular operating system?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I am using a windows 8.1 OS, but would love if it could apply to as low as Windows 7 and up to Windows 10.

Comment: I believe that is the default behaviour for at least Windows 8 and later

Comment: @RowlandShaw it is not. I publish my Windows 8 WPF application and when I open it up on a tablet it does not popup with a keyboard.

Comment: Ah, it may be because when I tested this, it was with a Windows 8 app. Could it be an option to migrate to being an app (universal or otherwise), although I appreciate that then removes support for Windows 7 customers.

Comment: @RowlandShaw I'm using the C# and XAML aspect of WPF. I do not know the steps I'd need to take to migrate it to a Windows 8 application.

Comment: Windows 8(+) apps can be based on C# and XAML. The scope of migrating is possibly a bit large to cover as an answer here, but there are [resources on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj984633.aspx)

Comment: @RowlandShaw the problem I have is this will be a private application used within the organization. It should not be available through the Microsoft store. When I attempt to make a WindowsRT it prompts me saying it must be tested by Microsoft.

Comment: It is possible to [sideload apps in corporate environments](https://blogs.windows.com/itpro/2014/04/03/windows-8-1-update-sideloading-enhancements/)

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't have time to convert my application from WPF to WindowsRT. So the solution I am looking for is to detect hardware changes and initialize the OSK when a textbox is in focus.